# Test statistics of LMM with significant covariate interaction

Tags: r, mixed-model, post-hoc

When reporting on the LMM that I fitted to my data with R, I was asked to include the test statistics (df and others). But I have no idea where to extract them from, I don't see them in the summary as I do in summaries of other LM's I've fitted before.

I've 10 weeks of aphid count data on leaves under 5 treatments. Each treatments was applied on 4 plots (replicates). To avoid excess of 0's I took the mean no. aphids/leaf of each plot on each sampling day.

I've fitted a LMM to the data, with log(aphids+1) as response variable (aphids as mean no. aphids/leaf), treatment as fixed effect, time (in days) as covariate and replicate as random effect.

The post hoc comparison with `emmeans()` showed me that change (increase) in aphid numbers through time differs significantly between treatment E and all the other treatments. So I've included those p-values in my text, but need to add other test statistics as well.

1) Which ones do I need to add? I assume at least degrees of freedom, but what else? Chi²?

2) Where do I find them?

**Code**

```
# packages
library(lme4)
library(emmeans)

# data
aphids <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.1,0,0,0,0.033,0.067,0,
             0.333,0,0,0,0.067,0.4,0,0.033,0.2,0.233,0.433,0,0.033,2.233,0,0.567,0.033,0.6,0,
             0.433,0,0.167,2.6,1.1,0,4.4,0,0.633,12.867,6.4,6.467,0,0.1,2.267,0.033,0.867,0.033,
             1,0,0.267,0.867,0.067,0.9,0.3,0.233,1.867,0.133,6.967,21.233,10.2,11.5)
time <- rep(c(0,14,22,27), each=20)
treatment <- rep(rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"),each=4),4)
replicate <- rep(c("A1","A2","A3","A4","B1","B2","B3","B4","C1","C2","C3","C4",
                   "D1","D2","D3","D4","E1","E2","E3","E4"),4)
data <- data.frame(aphids, time, treatment, replicate)

# LMM
model <- lmer(log(aphids+1) ~ treatment * time + (1|replicate), data)
drop1(model, test="Chisq") #interaction effect significant
summary(model)

# post hoc comparison
em <- emtrends(model, pairwise ~ treatment, var = "time") 
em #all experimental treatments differ from control
```

Comment: "df and others" ? Please can you be specific. What exactly have you been asked for ?

Comment: Well "other" was what it said, but I think I figured it out:

I was focused on the pairwise comparisons and their p-values (as the comment was there) and they had no statistics, nor the summary of the model. But drop1 gives test statistics for treatment-effect on aphid numbers: df, Chi² and p-value.

So now I give those three when I state that a significant effect of treatment was found and then give p-values when reporting pairwise differences between treatments.

Is that correct?

(the comments about me having to add test statistics were rather poorly placed in my draft I think)